# linux - $JAVA_HOME

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu

New to `Linux ubuntu`

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

returns "There is only one alternative in link group java (providing `/usr/bin/java`) `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java`"

Really I just wanna set the $JAVA_HOME because I think I'll use it later.

I think i have to copy (as in Ctrl+c) "`/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java`" and set it as the `$JAVA_HOME` but not sure if that's correct because of the "providing" statement mentioned above. I'm not sure what "providing" means. :(

also, how do I copy (Ctrl+c) the returned folder address?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to set JAVA_HOME unless you want to ensure that a specific Java is the one you use.  In your case, you only have one specific Java installed.

That said, if you really want to configure this, add the following lines to your ~/.bashrc file

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/
export JAVA_HOME
```

If you are going to go this route, I suggest also adding to your PATH

```
PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
export PATH
```

somewhere below the JAVA_HOME lines detailed above.